# Setting Up Loopback to Function When Ethernet Disconnected

Tags: networking, ethernet

I'm currently running a fresh install of 14.04.  "ifconfig -a" lists the loopback address, however I cannot access the loopback interface (i.e., pass packets across it) unless a networking cable is plugged in.  As soon as Ubuntu recognizes that a cable has been disconnected (from either eth0 or eth1), I am no longer able to pass packets via loopback.

Is there anyway I can configure the kernel to always allow the loopback address to pass data regardless of what is happening with the physical Ethernet connection?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Edited to add:
Confirmed that the application is using TCP and the loopback address (127.0.0.1).  However, packets will only go through if a networking devices is active.  Otherwise, I can still ping loopback, but the packets don't go through.  Going to contact the vendor of the application with this information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The loopback interface is always up unless you're somehow explicitly disabling it. However, only local addresses (127.x.x.x, ::1) are routable on it.

Comment: This is what I suspected.  I will check what address/port the application is sending/receiving on and let you know.

Comment: Looks like the application is hosed and won't send unless an Ethernet connection is made.  Going to contact the vendor.  I can still ping 127.0.0.1 just fine when the network is disconnected, but I can't run the application.